# Implementing client server instant messaging using zmq library. I have basic approach of handling each client in seprate threads

Tags: multithreading, sockets, zeromq, instant-messaging

Implementing client server instant messaging using zmq library. I have basic approach of handling each client in separate threads. Should I use dealers and routers or REQ-REP fashion.How would I identify client IDs? How would I handle each client in separate thread with communication between different clients.

Answer (score 0):

### An initial remark

For more than a few tens of users, the above sketched approach, consuming one thread per each user, would get an immense ( if not blocking ) thread management overhead.

### A next step for creating a proper System Architecture

For ID#s, state-signalling, content-transport(s), load-balancing and similar system design features the best next step would be to

write a **System Requirement List** and complete each item with it's quantified levels ( both the expected level & a maximum acceptable level ) be it in [ms], [us], [kB], [MSGs/s] or [MB/s]

This way one can design an appropriate messaging layer and test it.

ZeroMQ is a great toolkit for this, however, the design is in your hands.